# Open Word document, based on search pattern, goto that page

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell, we successfully extracted data we wanted using below command:

```
Get-Content $SourceFileName |
    Select-String -Pattern "search keywords"
```

Requirement: Open Word doc, search for pattern provided to function, if found goto that page (this should open word doc for end user by going to that page where it found that search term)

- This opens Word doc but doesn't take to the right line (LINE 534 I want to goto)

  ```
  Set-Variable -Name wdGoToLine -Value 3 -Option Constant
  Set-Variable -Name wdGoToAbsolute -Value 1 -Option Constant
  $t = $true
  $f = $false
  $a = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
  $a.Visible = $true
  $b = $a.Documents.Open("D:\Scan.doc", $f, $t)
  $c = $a.Selection
  $d = $c.GoTo($wdGoToLine, $wdGoToAbsolute, 534)
  ```
- This takes me to right line, but doesn't open Word document for me:

  ```
  Get-Content D:\Scan.doc -TotalCount 534 | Select-Object -Last 3;
  ```

LINE NUMBER by above commands are different. `Get-Content` gives 534 for one pattern and `Word.Application` gives 1090 for same content. why that would have happened?

Comment: [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve]. Code ***requests*** and even  recommendations are definitely OFF-TOPIC.

Comment: added the code so far tried, and issues im facing.

Comment: Word documents are organized in paragraphs, not lines.

Comment: Please do not add tags to the subject of your question.

Comment: Words `.doc` file is usually a `binary` format. If you get proper lines with `Get-Content` then it seems to be a plain text file with just the extension `.doc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started

```
# set these to your liking
$file = "D:\Scan.docx"
$textToFind = "find me"
$matchWildcards = $false 
$matchCase = $true

# some Word constants
$wdFindStop = 0
$wdActiveEndPageNumber = 3
$wdStory = 6
$wdGoToPage = 1
$wdGoToAbsolute = 1

# Documents.Open switches
$ReadOnly = $false  # when ReadONly was set to $true, it gave me an error on 'Selection.GoTo()' 
                    # 'This method or property is not available because this command is not available for reading.' 
$ConfirmConversions = $false

$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $true
$doc = $word.Documents.Open($file, $ConfirmConversions, $ReadOnly)
$range = $doc.Content
$range.Find.ClearFormatting(); 
$range.Find.Forward = $true 
$range.Find.Text = $textToFind
$range.Find.Wrap = $wdFindStop
$range.Find.MatchWildcards = $matchWildcards
$range.Find.MatchCase = $matchCase
$range.Find.Execute()
if ($range.Find.Found) {
    # get the pagenumber
    $page = $range.Information($wdActiveEndPageNumber)
    Write-Host "Found '$textToFind' on page $page" -ForegroundColor Green
    [void] $word.Selection.GoTo($wdGoToPage, $wdGoToAbsolute, $page)
}
else {
    Write-Host "'$textToFind' not found" -ForegroundColor Red
    [void] $word.Selection.GoTo($wdGoToPage, $wdGoToAbsolute, 1)
}

# cleanup com objects
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($range) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($doc) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Getting this error when i deployed it on our server - The script failed due to call depth overflow

Comment: The script failed due to call depth overflow.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CallDepthOverflow

Comment: what version of Powershell are you using? (i tested on PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10 Pro with Office 2016 installed)

Comment: If you are repeating this without exiting Powershell, please make sure to release the used Com objects when done: `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($range) | Out-Null ; [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($doc) | Out-Null ; [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word) | Out-Null ; [System.GC]::Collect() ; [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()`. I have edited the answer to do just that.

Comment: when im running this, its opening the word doc on server.... I want this to open on client's computer...

Comment: it's opening the document on the machine where the script is running from of course.. If you want it to run on a different machine, you'll need to copy the script there first and have that machine perform it.

Comment: OR place the script on a server share that is accessible to the client machine. Have the client machine then run it using the complete path. You'll need to make sure the client pc has Excel installed ofcourse.

Comment: all this im doing through asp.net webapp, client will upload docs and then it should open that doc with search pattern. i can put on some share path. But how in dotnet execute this on client side

Comment: well... this is now becoming a completely different question. Please post this new requirements as a new question. This way it will get the attention of a lot more people.